# Ranking with mysql: update vs select

Tags: mysql, sql-update, ranking, sql

I am developing a web game with a lot of users. On the main screen there will be a map with many markers. Each marker is linked to an user and each user has a position in a ranking (calculated with their points) that I want to show.

To dynamically calculate the position of the ranking have found the following from [here](http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/how-to-get-rank-using-mysql-query/):

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SELECT rank, points FROM (
                    SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, points, uid
                    FROM landings ORDER BY points DESC
                    ) as result WHERE uid=xxxxxxxx
```

But this query will be fired for every new marker loaded to the map, every time a player moves the map to an unexplored zone.

On the other hand, what if every time a player finish a game I update a rank field for every user on the database? This sounds huge, of course, but this scenario is less frequent than the other. What do you think? An update is much less efficient than a select? How much?

Thank you for your help!

Edit for more explainations: This draw shows the screen. There is a map with a lot of markers, and for every marker  in the screen the query that I explain before is triggered (when I load the markers by AJAX). The other option is that every time an user plays a game and, of course, modifies his total amount of points, a supposed "rank" field in the database would be updated for every user on the database. 
[image]

Comment: can you please more clear your problem

Comment: I edited the question with a draw. Perhaps its a langague problem? My english could be better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to say which one is going to be more efficient. It totally depends on the number of updates to the points column, the total number of records in the table, and the number of rank requests. If you know the numbers or you can make a good guess, benchmark it with random test data. If you can't, go with the solution which is easiest to implement and improve on it if it ever becomes a problem.

Comment: My problem is that I don't have experience with databases and I don't have the notion of how much efficient is the select that I purposed, or a similar update. With this info I could think with the variables that you explain (number of entries... frequency of updating). Of course, I suppose that I would have to let the time pass and wait until a problem appears, but this is a project with a short live time, where every hour counts, and information about the costs of the queries will be very appreciated.

Comment: I see. Here's some timing data I made using a MySQL InnoDB table with 400k records (all of which InnoDB keeps in RAM), each with a handful of fields. Updating one field in each record takes about 2 seconds on my 3.1GHz Core i3. Updating a field with an index on it increases the query time to about 8s.

Comment: The ranking SELECT query above takes about 270ms, with an index on both the points and the uid field. If I don't calculate the rank on the fly but select another field from the table instead (like you would do if you had ranking data updated on every game), query time drops to 1ms.

Comment: So the timing you'll see will easily be off by orders of magnitude (except for the last case, probably), because it also depends on the byte size of each record, on your hardware, on the amount of memory you can dedicate to MySQL, on the overall load on the machine, on how many concurrent queries there will be, etc. If I had to decide which way to go, and if I'd expect less than about one update to the ranking per second, I'd go without a real rank field in the database and cache the ranked entries (the result of the inner SELECT query) outside of the database.